# How to Configure Test Deployment with the file LocalTestRun.testrunconfig?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, nhibernate

First of all sorry if the question is not very clear.
I am learning nHibernate from the [summerofnhibernate.com](http://summerofnhibernate.com/), in the first chapter when I run a test project, I get the following error: Test method TestProject1.NHibernateDataProviderTestTest.CanGetCustomerByIdTest threw exception:  NHibernate.HibernateException: problem parsing configuration : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies;PrivateAssemblies\hibernate.cfg.xml'.

I have googled the problem, and the search says that the VS 2008 path is wrong(buggy), to place hibernate.cfg.xml in test project and adding the attribute: [TestMethod(), DeploymentItem("hibernate.cfg.xml")]
After having done this I still get the same problem.

But when I use Visual Studio 2010 I get the following error:
Test method TestProject1.NHibernateDataProviderTestTest.CanGetCustomerByIdTest threw exception: 
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like 2 different problems.

For the first place nhibernate.cfg.xml in the Project and give the path to `new Configuration("Path to hibernate.cfg.xml")` somewhere in the testsetup.

The Second looks like the getmethod returns null because it cant finde the Customer with given id in the database. If you use SQLite inMemory a typical captcha is, that each new Connection points to a different Database -> Open Sessions with `sf.OpenSession(theOneConnection)` or `Session.Clear()` instead of creating a new one.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Basically , (depends on your question : **How to Configure Test Deployment with the file LocalTestRun.testrunconfig?**)

Here is the way that you can follow:

To select files or folders to deploy, in run configuration

In Solution Explorer, under Solution Items, double-click the run configuration file that you want to edit.

A dialog box that has a name such as .testrunconfig appears.
Click Deployment.

Under Additional files or directories to deploy, specify additional files or folders to be copied.

To do this, 
click Add file to select files; this opens the Add Deployment Files dialog box.

You can also click Add Directory to select folders by using the Add Deployment Directory dialog box.

In the .testrunconfig dialog box, click Save and then click OK.

These deployment items will be copied to the deployment folder whenever this run configuration file is active.

Hope this will help.